# Export projet APK: Java heap space during eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a message error when I want to export my applications Android to APK file.

When I choose the folder to save the apk file, and after a few minutes the message error show: Java heap space error occurred during.

Part of the `eclipse.ini` is:

---

```
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_65\bin\javaw.exeargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6``
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

---

Picture of the problem

[image]

Comment: Have you set the JAVA_HOME variable? http://www.wikihow.com/Set-Java-Home

Comment: Yes I have set the Java home but the problem no fix yet